# Best practice to auto export node functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

## Goal

I'm new to node and I'm trying to write a code in a way where I don't have to keep track of exporting everysingle functions that I've wrote in that file.

---

## Steps

I have a function

*general.js*

```
import request from 'request-promise'
import env from 'dotenv'
const dotenv = env.config();

function getInfo(req, res)
{
    var $mac    = req.body.mac;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({ uri: `${process.env.API_HOST}/${$mac}` })
            .then((cpe) => resolve(JSON.parse(cpe).data))
            .catch((error) => reject(error));
    });

}

module.exports = {
    getInfo
};
```

How would I adjust it so that my functions are export automatically ?

---

I've tried

```
import request from 'request-promise'
import env from 'dotenv'
const dotenv = env.config();

module.exports = () => {
    let general = {};

    general.getInfo = ($mac) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request({ uri: `${process.env.API_HOST}/${$mac}` })
                .then((count) => resolve(JSON.parse(count).data))
                .catch((error) => reject(error));
        });
    }
    return general;
}
```

I kept getting

> Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

How can I debug this further?

Comment: remove `() =>` from the module exports code.

Comment: Please show us where you import and use the exported function. I suspect you want to export the function and not an object containing the function, in which case you'd do `module.exports = getInfo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just put your functions directly into the exports object:

```
module.exports = {
  getInfo(req, res) {
    //...
  },
  // type here ...
};
```

Or you move over to Typescript, then you can do:

```
export function getInfo(req, res) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: I've tried your first option, I still get this error 

`Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
`

Comment: its `getInfo` ?

Answer (score 1):

So, you would like to write some functions in a file, and they should all be exported just because they are functions? Not possible I'm afraid. You have to export explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it like this:

```
exports.getInfo = (req, res) => {
    var $mac = req.body.mac;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({ uri: `${process.env.API_HOST}/${$mac}` })
            .then((cpe) => resolve(JSON.parse(cpe).data))
            .catch((error) => reject(error));
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well to be honest, I haven't found a *guide* for best practices. The post that I read and it was quite clear on *how things should be done* is [this one.](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/)

If we take your code for an example, we could modify it it like this:

```
 module.exports = {
    let general = {};
     general.getInfo = ($mac) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request({ uri: `${process.env.API_HOST}/${$mac}` })
                .then((count) => resolve(JSON.parse(count).data))
                 .catch((error) => reject(error));
        });
     } }
```

Removing the **arrow function** should resolve your error.

Now wherever you want to *access* your export, you simply type the variable name that you want to use for the given export. In your case, we can call it **info**:

```
var info = require('./yourJSfileName.js')
```

This requires from you to have the **require** package installed ( no puns intended).

Then you can use: `info.theFunctionName();` to call your exported function. I hope that helps, I can go in more depth if you want me to.